# How to force a new login if the server session ends?

Tags: web-services, session, smart-device, genexus

I've been developing "online" Smart Devices Applications in GeneXus.
When the user stops using the application for a while, the remote server session automatically ends. As I use a lot of websession variables, if the user attempts to continue using the app, it becomes non responsive.
I am thinking on a way to prevent the user to keep using the App if the remote session ends. I would like to force him to do a new login procedure (I am not using GAM).

Do I have to create a websession variable to validate if the session is valid and test it against **all** my procedures and **all** server-side events? What's the best approach?

Comment: Even if I create a procedure to test the websession, it will never be possible to interact with the user with a message right?

Comment: I tried to test the websession in the Refresh event but it disables the interaction with the user (eg, a "please login again" message). I honestly don't know how to achieve this...

Comment: Implementing your own security model is hard, you should probably not do it... Why not use GAM?

Comment: This App is a client for an external system. It basically consumes WebServices and presents the data from this source. So, the security model involves consuming an external authentication method. Can I use GAM is this scenario? Should I? Does GAM automatically request a new login if the session expires? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some elements that may help you:
Try to store the websession in a stateserver or sql server so that it doesn't expire just because asp.net recycles, for example – for the case you are in .NET. [Read this](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?4326)

Another option may be using [ClientStart Event](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?24044), may be creating an external object to check connectivity and session state may help.

GAM: Try using GAM, with it your app will be more secure. You can use GAM in this case! You can delegate authentication and authorization too. Please check out [GAM External Authentication](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?16512) and [GAM External Authorization](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?22898), and [GAM Respository features and properties](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?18463) for session expiration handling.

Comment: I guess the best option is to use the GAM approach. I'll try that. Thank you.